# How can memory leak occur if I resolve from root life time scope?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, autofac

Refer to the Autofac docs [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/v6.0.0/lifetime/index.html):

> I**t is important to always resolve services from a lifetime scope and
> not the root container.** Due to the disposal tracking nature of
> lifetime scopes, if you resolve a lot of disposable components from
> the container (the “root lifetime scope”), you may inadvertently cause
> yourself a memory leak. The root container will hold references to
> those disposable components for as long as it lives (usually the
> lifetime of the application) so it can dispose of them.

I don't understand how can memory leak occur if I resolve components/services using the root container/root life time scope, instead of using LifeTimeScope as suggested.

In my WPF MVVM application, I setup my container and resolve the services ( eg: ViewModels and loggers) at the OnStartup event. I will resolve relevant services from the Autofac container from time to time when the WPF application is running. So I will of course need the reference to the container. So what memory leak we are talking about?

The benefits of LifeTimeScope is that you can control when the container is disposed, but in my case, the container is not disposed until the application is shut down, and I won't want it to dispose earlier because I need it from time to time.

So how can a memory leak be inadvertently caused?

Comment: Every service in the root scope is effectively a singleton. It will hang around until the application closes. Every service in a lifetime scope will be released and disposed when that lifetime is released. For example you could create a new lifetime scope per screen.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving components directly from the root scope results in Autofac keeping a reference to the component for the entire lifecycle of the application which prevents the component from being garbage collected.

This is not a classic memory leak when you lose reference to a memory block and thus you are unable to deallocate the memory block, so it remains allocated but never used.
Components resolved from the root scope can **effectively** cause a memory leak because they are never disposed and remain in the memory even if your application logic doesn't reference it directly and doesn't use it ever again after the first resolve.

By disposing the child scope you give Autofac a hint that the component is no longer needed and it can be safely disposed of.